# MySQL statement that has identity attribute

Tags: mysql

I am a MySQL beginner, I followed a simple tutorial on the web, it has such a simple create table statement

```
create table users(
userID int primary key identity(1,1)
)
```

I now sort of have an idea of what identity means, however, whenever I typed this statement in MySQL console, it always complains that I have a syntax error.

Could anybody help out? Thanks.

Comment: The `IDENTITY` keyword is Transact-SQL (e.g. for [tag:sql-server]); it is not supported by MySQL.  What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Identity(1,1)` is not mysql syntax; use `auto_increment` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this syntax

```
CREATE TABLE users(
userID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(userID  )
);
```

Your syntax if proper to sql server

Answer (score 1):

Identity is used to auto-increment the field value for a new row.

> Identity(increment, seed)

.
Having said that I don't think mysql supports that at all. I have seen that in sql-server. In mysql `auto_increment` is used.